# Which components a v-bind:is can render

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component which registers 15+ external components.
In the template there is a dynamic component like so:

```html
<template>
  <component :is="config.name" />
</template>
```

Is there a way to limit the dynamic components the `:is` can select from?
I know that only a few of those 15+ components are actually used by the dynamic component. But I would like to be able to restrict it to a specific list.

Comment: @kissu yes, thanks. Well in the direction at least. And also I posted on the features discussions for Vue3.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot limit the list to a specific ones, the only thing that you can do is to use a `exclude/include` on the `<keep-alive></keep-alive>` component to keep them cached, as explained here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

```html
<keep-alive :include="['a', 'b']">
  <component :is="view"></component>
</keep-alive>
```

But **you** can totally filter the `:is` dynamic component with a `filter` + `includes` or alike.

```js
const allowedComponents = ['header', 'footer']
const arrayOfReceivedComponents = ['header', 'section', 'about']
const intersection = arrayOfReceivedComponents.filter((x) => allowedComponents.includes(x))
// intersection >> ["header"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but that is not what I needed. My issue also with `keep-alive` stays the same. The moment `:is` is written in the template, it is impossible to track which components are actually being used and which are not.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you do mean by this. How are you expecting to "track" components, and what for?

Comment: If I import many components into a single Vue component, eslint will monitor which ones are being used. The moment `:is` is present in the template it can't monitor anymore which components are being used. Also if I have two `:is` statements I can't see which imported - component can be assigned to which `:is`.

Comment: You can totally lazy load the components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components I don't think that ESlint will be angry at you if you do it this way. If it still is, you can still mute it for the few import lines. As for several `:is`, you can totally check the `computed` value of the component's name you're passing to `:is`, or simply inspect the dynamic component with your vue devtools.

Comment: lol, kidding or for real? You cannot monitor which one is used with ESlint because it depends of the state of your current app and ESlint cannot be plugged to it, it's not it's job.

Comment: Eslint is just an example. The issue is that I do not have an option to limit straight forward which components might be rendered by the `:is`.

Comment: Why not using a computed property, where you do filter at first (as shown in my answer)? This will totally limit the components that can be used in a "whitelist" way. What is wrong with this? And again, there is no real limitation features for dynamic components.

Comment: Yes, your approach will solve part of my problem, but it still not gives me the full approach I wanted. And as you said there is no built-in feature for limiting dynamic-components.

Comment: I do appreciate your help though :)

Comment: Sorry for not having a magic trick. ^^ You could maybe submit this idea to the rfc repo (vue3): https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs