# 'include' pages using 'nuxt.js' 'keep-alive' are not cached

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

'include' pages using 'nuxt.js' 'keep-alive' are not cached.

```html
<Nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{exclude: ['pages/basket.vue']}" />
```

I tried the method above.
Excluded by `yarn dev`, but not by `yarn generate`.
Do you know how to exclude it in `yarn generate` as well?

environment
"nuxt": "2.15.8",
"vue": "2.6.14",

Referenced site
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components/#keep-alive

add

I want to include or ignore certain pages.

```
<Nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{include: ['pages/basket.vue']}" />
```

All pages are uncached, including 'pages/basket.vue'.

```
<Nuxt keep-alive />
```

All pages are cached, including 'pages/basket.vue'.

Comment: So, you want to include or exclude a specific one? Also, do you have a [repro] or any more context?

Comment: that's right.  
I want to include or ignore certain pages.  


```
<Nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{include: ['pages/basket.vue']}" />
```
All pages are uncached, including 'pages/basket.vue'.


```
<Nuxt keep-alive />
```
All pages are cached, including 'pages/basket.vue'.

Comment: `keep-alive` is not a "cache" per-se. It's more of a component state preservation (by not destroying it). But it all depends on your lifecycle + the name of the component itself. As shown in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67401739/8816585), the [Nuxt doc](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components#keep-alive) and the [vue doc](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#keepalive). The initial code snippet should work (even tho, I'm not sure about the `pages/` part). Try to have a working example with a component at first.

Comment: Have you manage to solve it? Any update? @ema

Comment: @lukas23 doesn't look like so. Do you have an issue with it too? My answers above did not helped?